# Can I run project on older version of Xcode and iOS Simulator

Tags: xcode, macos, project

Is it possible to run project from the newest version of XCode on an older version of XCode (older Mac with older XCode and iOS Simulator)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends. Storyboards will have trouble on older versions of Xcode as they are updated regularly. Some other new features may be a problem too, it really depends on your project.

You can download old simulators in the current Xcode from: Preferences > Downloads and then in components, but it doesn't go back very far, at the time of writing as far as iOS 7.1.

If your Mac is too old to run current Xcode/Yosemite you probably do need to upgrade your Mac sooner or later I'm afraid.